# Git Workflow Project and use of rebase

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-rebase

I am currently doing a course of Version control using git from coursera. There is a project which I have to complete and make a git workflow.
Here is the final gitflow graph of my project
[image]

My graph has 3 "feature 2 wip" commits but the other project graph has only one "feature 2 wip" commit.
Here is the gitflow graph of other project
[image]

I am not able to understand whether my graph is correct or the other project graph is correct. We have to follow the instructions given in the project. I am also attaching the images of the instructions as well. If I am wrong then please explain my mistake in detail.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally done it. Use Rebase interactively and feature 2 wip is required only once with the latest commit and the old ones can be merged into the new ones.